# how to train intent " Find average of salary of employees with following id_numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6]" with entitities?

Tags: training-data, entities, rasa, rasa-nlu

I have to create an RASA chatbot where I need to train an intent which asks for the average of salary of employees at a company where the user enters specific employee id numbers.

So instead of : what is the mean [salaries]{"entity":"column"}  , where the salaries of all the employees is taken into consideration the user specifies  certain id_numbers . Should it come like this :  what is the mean [salaries]{"entity":"column"} of the employees with ids [1 [1,2,3,4,5,6]{"entity":"string"}. Is this correct??